# What is the difference between an ActionListener and an EventListener in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, event-listener

What is the difference between an ActionListener and an EventListener, especially in the context of Java GUI development?

Comment: ActionListener is one of the extending interfaces of EventListener. Some other are `TextListener`, `WindowListener`.

Comment: Neither of them are types, they are both interfaces.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle.. Actually I meant interfaces only. thanks .

Answer (score 7):

The interface `ActionListener` is a subinterface of `EventListener`. In practice, it is probably better to implement the most specific interface you can, such as `ActionListener` or `WindowListener`.

Comment: Given that there are no methods to implement in the case of `EventListener`, I'm actually not sure what the point of `EventListener` is, since there is very limited polymorphism utility. It's useful for storing collections of listeners, I guess?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure A means by which all event listener interfaces can be grouped under a single, common, family.  It allows for management classes to be used to manage a wide range of event listeners (such as the `EventListenerList`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's what I was getting at with "It's useful for storing collections of listeners, I guess" above. In general, though, the power of polymorphism in collections lies in the ability to invoke behavior based on the contract defined by the interface, and `EventListener` supplies no such contract as far as I am aware.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure It does.  It's like `Serializable`, it provides a common level contract that allows slightly finer access control, over just allowing objects.  Why your observations are correct, the `EventListener` is just a "common level" access interface that allows for broader access control.  You have to remember, this was in the day before generics

Answer (score 1):

The ActionListener interface is utilized for treating action events. For illustration, it's used for button clicks by a JButton, for checking  by JCheckbox and unchecking, by a JMenuItem when an option is picked and a lot of other graphical components.

It's a uncomplicated interface with only one technique:

```
 public interface ActionListener extends EventListener

 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
 }
```

An event listener is used to practice events. For instance, a graphical component similar to a JButton or JTextField is acknowledged as event sources.

This indicates they can generate events - when a user relates to on the JButton or types text into the JTextField. The event listener’s job is to catch those events and do incredible with them.

Answer (score 1):

[Although the meaning can differ by platform](https://coderanch.com/t/645943/java/Difference-EventHandler-ActionListener), in the context of Java Swing an `ActionListener` implements a function `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` that will do something *when a user does some action*, according to this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). An `ActionListener` is a subinterface of `EventListener`. `EventListener` contains several subinterfaces, for example `MouseWheelListener`, which does something when the user moves the mouse wheel.